# Opening an Excel spreadsheet by making Excel an OLE object

Tags: excel, delphi, pascal, lazarus, ole-automation

I have tried using the following code to open a spreadsheet I have created in Excel. It runs, but a popup keeps coming up saying that my file has been deleted or moved. The file definitely still exists. I have tried creating new files with other names. none of them work.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Excelfile: Variant;
  Workbook: Variant;
begin
  Excelfile := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  Workbook := Excelfile.workbooks.open('filename.xls');
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a fully-qualified (absolute) path, not a relative path.

- Good: `C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Documents\Report.xls`
- Bad: `Report.xls`

(Indeed, if I'd ask you to go to the red cottage in Sweden, you'd certainly ask me about the precise address.)

Comment: Tavastehusgatan 26, 164 79 Kista, Sweden, right? :-)

Comment: @Jerry: No, that seems to be "The Red Cottage" (with capital letters! :)